# Is there any difference between type and class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm reading a Python book and it always speaks about "given X its type is Y", so I'm getting confused.

Is there any difference between asking the **type** of an object and the **class** of  membership of an object in python2 and python3?

I mean, are type and class two different concepts?

This question comes from the fact that in pythons previous to the 2.1 there was a difference between calling `x.__class__` and `type(x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to Python 2.2, there **was** a difference between "[classic] classes" and "[built-in] types."

Basically, you couldn't subclass built-in types and they had other idiosyncratic behavior that made them different from user-defined classes.

[This blog post](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/new-style-classes.html) from Python creator Guido van Rossum explains some of the motivation for the unification of user-defined classes and built-in types under the framework of "new-style classes."

The Python wiki also has some good background on [the practical differences between the classic and new-style user-defined classes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass).

**tl;dr:** In Python 2.7 you can still create a "classic class," for backwards compatibility, but the built-in types behave as new-style classes.

Comment: so prior to Python 2.2, eveything, in some way, was an instance of a built-in type, I mean even a class was an instance of the built-in type `instance`, the **class** was only a label to differentiate to which particular instance of a class an object belongs. Is that right?

Comment: That's basically right: user-defined classic classes, when instantiated, produced objects with the generic `instance` type, with some class-specific attributes and methods glommed onto it. I think GvR's blog post, which I linked to, gives some more insight into it. If you stick with new-style classes you'll never have to think about these things in modern Python.

Answer (score 2):

No, type and class means the same.

Though, builtin types and C-extension (interpreter extension at all, like Java classes in Jython) may be treated a little differently, for example you may not be able to monkey-patch it. In old versions of CPython there was also an issue with subclassing builtins, but that was so long ago, that I only read about it, and haven't seen "in action".

Also, there is difference with old- and new-style classes in Python2, but it's not really important in this context.

In the end there are many "types of types", but names "class" and "type" are equivalent. Still - "type" is used more often for builtins, while class - not so often. With not-builtins both names are as frequent.

Comment: This is not true in older versions of Python; see my answer above. Probably @antox is reading a book or documentation written for an older version of Python, which may be a source of confusion.

Comment: I provided short answer first, then I edited post and enhanced it. We seem to have posted within a minute or so ;)